# Running npm-scripts on node

Tags: javascript, node.js, scripting, npm

I am trying to get away from using Grunt or Gulp in my projects.  I thought that a good way to replace them is by using npm-scripts.

I know that npm-scripts leverages `package.json`, but I noticed that to run more advanced build processes, you need to include command line functions.  However, this is not a cross-platform solution since Windows doesn't support the wide variety of commands that an OS like Linux supports.

So, I was wondering if you could just run npm-scripts on Node, and just reference any npm package you want to with a `require` statement.

Is this possible?  If not, are there any good cross-platform solutions that exist for npm-scripts excluding Grunt and Gulp?

Comment: A must read on using `npm` as a build tool, if you want to put Gulp and Grunt behind: http://blog.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/

Comment: @Healforgreen How did it go? Did you do away with grunt & gulp?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you could run "npm-scripts on node". For instance I have this in my `package.json` (irrelevant parts are removed for clarity), and both [rimraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rimraf) and [webpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack) are implemented in pure JS and interpreted by node.js. In fact `rimraf` is a good example of cross platform `rm -Rf`. This solution runs fine on windows, mac or linux boxes by just issuing `npm run-script build`.

```
{
    "scripts": {
       "build": "rimraf dist && webpack --config ./blah.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "rimraf": "^2.5.0",
        "webpack": "^1.12.10"
    }
}
```

Or you could do something like:

```
"scripts": {
    "hello": "node hello"
}
```

And implement everything you want in `hello.js` in the same dir as your `package.json`, and include whatever you need in that script like:

```
const hello = require("debug")("hello"); // require whatever module you need
console.log("hello world");
```

It would run just fine with `npm run-script hello`

```
> your-module@1.0.0 hello D:\dev\tmp
> node hello

hello world
```

Comment: Hell yeah, that's awesome.

Answer (score 0):

I would stick with webpack and npm only. Using webpack is much simpler than writing custom grunt or gulp tasks, dev server will give a stable local enviornment to work, and it is just a config setup and you are golden. I would also move away from using global installs especially if you work team environment or are running continuous delivery. As you won't be able to control the global installation or installed version on any of these environments.